# Tandy CoCo 2 Game involving managing a set of shops in a fantasy world

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I have, unfortunately, forgotten a lot of these details, but somewhere in the late 1980s to the early 1990s (we got the computer in mid elementary school, and I'm pretty sure this was before high school). The game involved some method of investing in shops. I think there was a standard set of names, and I remember some of them were puns that I didn't get at the time, like reference to "Knight wear" for an underwear store. I think one of the other stores was about either taxes or accounting (I know... weird thing to have stick in my head). There was a standard set of stores (maybe 50 of them), but more were available with an option (I think it displayed the standard list, then there was something else you typed in that let you scroll through a few hundred, or you could type in the corresponding number. I think the numbering was consistent between playthroughs). The other thing I remember was that it was possible to illicitly access the shops at night, where you'd often be confronted with a set of choices with different metal door knobs (in my memory, they were drawers, but doors make more sense) where I recall one of them invoked a spell to give you a nasty shock if you picked it. I'm 99% certain one of the knobs was described as being "silver".

This was implemented in BASIC. I remember that because I figured out how to halt the program, and move around the program's logic to cheat, although my understanding was pretty rudimentary, basically forcing a GOTO to a particular section. It might have been something my brother typed in from [*The Rainbow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rainbow_(magazine)) magazine.

Comment: _"basically forcing a GOTO"_ -> You Monster!

Comment: ^_^ Well, you know, a GOSUB would not have been sufficient in that case.

Comment: +1 I started my journey into software engineering by learning how to do stuff like that to the BASIC games on the PDPs that a local college let kids play on.

Comment: Were there any other Tandy magazines or books your brother might have typed this in from? There's a list of magazines with links to scans at https://colorcomputerarchive.com/repo/Documents/Magazines/ and a similar list of books at https://colorcomputerarchive.com/repo/Documents/Books/ . Do any of the titles in either of these lists look familiar?

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern We did, at one point, have a subscription to *Rainbow* magazine, so it is possible. I've done some text searches for keywords with no luck.

Comment: Could it have been this magazine: https://archive.org/details/metamorphosismag (Disclaimer, I have not yet looked at those scans to see if they *do* contain type-ins.)

Comment: If we ignore the bit about breaking into shops - there is a similar type-in game at https://colorcomputerarchive.com/repo/Documents/Books/Computer%20Space%20Adventures%20(Stephen%20Manes%20and%20Paul%20Somerson).pdf - although the companies here are space companies ("Martian Goldmines", "Venus Space Suits", "Photon Torpedo Inc"...) and not medieval ones.